# USB gadget serial-port (g_serial or composite): how do I control what name Windows will see?

Tags: kernel, drivers, usb, windows, serial-port

I'm trying to add a gadget-serial interface to my project, either by way of `modprobe g_serial` or by way of a `composite`/`configfs` method.

I have a little script (shown below) that works perfectly when talking to a MacOS or a Linux host. And it also works when talking to a Windows host, except that the name is always wrong.

When connected to a Windows host, my gadget always shows up in the Device Manager as *"USB Serial Device (COM)"* instead of showing up with the right product name. Windows also lists the device's manufacturer as *Microsoft*, regardless of what I set in `strings/0x409/manufacturer`. And the gadget's serial-number is nowhere to be found.

How do I change this behavior? Is there some kind of magic I can do with `/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/usb_gadget/g1/os_desc` to make Windows pick up the `manufacturer`, `product`, and `serialnumber` fields correctly? Or is there some kind of .inf magic that I need to do on Windows?

I tried using `g_serial` originally, with the following command:

```
modprobe g_serial \
    idVendor="0x4075" \
    idProduct="0x0001" \
    iSerialNumber="0123456789" \
    iManufacturer="Magic Manufacturing" \
    iProduct="Gizmomatic Machine"
```

When I couldn't get the name to appear correctly, I tried a configfs/gadget-serial approach instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

mkdir /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1

echo 0xEF > bDeviceClass
echo 0x02 > bDeviceSubClass
echo 0x01 > bDeviceProtocol

echo "0x4075" > idVendor
echo "0x0001" > idProduct

mkdir strings/0x409
echo "0123456789" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "Magic Manufacturing" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "Gizmomatic Machine" > strings/0x409/product

mkdir configs/c.1
mkdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "acm" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration

mkdir functions/acm.usb0
ln -s functions/acm.usb0 configs/c.1

echo "ci_hdrc.0" > UDC
```

Both variants "work" in the sense that they create a working COM-port in Windows. But neither one reports the right serial-number, manufacturer, or product name. If anybody's got some words of wisdom here, it would help me out a lot. I'm on the 4.19.35 kernel if it matters.

Comment: have you deleted the gadget in the windows device manager and then replugged it?

Comment: I did, yeah - a couple of times. It's not the issue :(